# How to create a bottom tab navigation above bottomsheet in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create a bottom tab navigation in react native which is having a blur effect but as I am using it above the bottomsheet so navigation bar is getting hide or will have to manage with bottomInset property of bottomsheet.

This is tab navigation coming above bottom sheet
[image]

This is actually I want it to look

[image]

```
 <BottomSheet
      ref={bottomSheetRef}
      visible={bottomSheetVisible}
      onChangeCallback={onChangeCallback}
      enablePanDownToClose={false}
      header={header}
      bottomInset={84} // due to this I am able to add it above the bottomsheet
      style={styles.bottomSheet}
      renderBackdrop={renderBackdrop}>
 </BottomSheet>
```

**Custom Backdrop**

```
const CustomBackdrop = ({animatedIndex, style}: BottomSheetBackdropProps) => {
  // animated variables
  const containerAnimatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    opacity: interpolate(
      animatedIndex.value,
      [1, 1],
      [1, 1],
      Extrapolate.CLAMP,
    ),
  }));

  // styles
  const containerStyle = useMemo(
    () => [style, styles.container, containerAnimatedStyle],
    [style, containerAnimatedStyle],
  );

  return (
    <Animated.View style={containerStyle}>
      <View>
        <WalletHomeHeader />
        <WalletHomeCard />
      </View>
      <NavigationBar />
    </Animated.View>
  );
};

export default CustomBackdrop;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
});
```

**Style in Tab Navigator**

```
    tabBarActiveTintColor: theme.white,
    tabBarInactiveTintColor: theme.secondaryGrey,
    tabBarStyle: {
      position: 'absolute',
      bottom: 0,
      paddingVertical: scaleHeight(15),
      backgroundColor: convertHexToRGBA(theme.neutral_700, 0.5),
      borderTopWidth: 1,
      borderTopColor: theme.grey,
    },
```